# Watir web driver taking too long to get the selected item from drop down

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, watir

I am using watir web driver for web scraping, where I fill the form and get the results. The results also includes the dropdown list, from where I have to extracted the currently selected text. I have used following queries.

```
selectedList = browser.select_list(:id => "itemType")
```

From this i can use following query:

```
selectedText = selectedList.selected_options.map(&:text)[0]
```

Using this query, I am able to get the selected text. But the problem is, the drop-down list contains thousands of options, and watir is taking too long to find the selected option using this query.

Any faster method is appreciated.
Also I have tried with following queries:

```
selected = selectedList.selected_options()[0]
selectedText = selected.text
```

But the problem is same. I have other dropdowns with smaller options, where both of these queries are performing good, but with thousands of options, its really slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that to get the selected options, a call to the browser is made for each individual option. Even if each call takes a fraction of a second, it adds up quite quickly.

You could get the selected options in a single wire call by using `execute_script`:

```
selected_list  = browser.select_list(id: 'itemType')
selected_options = browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].selectedOptions;", selected_list)
selected_text = selected_options.map(&:text)
```

For a page with just a 1000 option select list, this dropped the execution time from 64 seconds to only 0.2 seconds.

The above works for both dropdowns and multi-selects. If you know it is a dropdown (ie single selected option), you could get even faster by just returning the text (rather than the collection of selected options):

```
selected_list  = browser.select_list(id: 'itemType')
selected_text = browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].selectedOptions[0].text;", selected_list)
```

This cut the time in half to 0.08 seconds. However, for such a small gain, I personally prefer the first approach as it minimizes the JavaScript code.

Comment: @Justin Ko: Thanks for your great answer, works like a charm.

Comment: I made this PR (https://github.com/watir/watir/pull/540) proposing that this javascript solution be the default implementation in Watir, since I don't think using Selenium to evaluate each option provides any additional benefit. Not sure if it is the right answer, but thanks for showing this alternative.